# Access of undefined property through static type

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got an error : access of possibly undefined property destinationY through a reference with static type Gold. I don't use the destinationY property in Gold class. Only in main class.
I'm still amateur at classes and defining properties for a object itself. Please help. Thanks!

Here is the Main class:

```
package
{   

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var field:Array;
        public var gold:Gold;
        public var goldContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var goldTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000);


        public function Main():void
        {
            setupField();

            goldSet();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
        }

        private function goldSet():void
        {   addChild(goldContainer);
            goldTimer.start();
            goldTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, newGold);

        }

        private function newGold(e:TimerEvent):void {
            var goldRow:int=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
            var goldCol:int=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
            gold = new Gold(this);
            gold.buttonMode=true;
            goldContainer.addChild(gold);
            gold.x=30+goldCol*65;
            gold.destinationY = 35+goldRow*75;
            gold.y=-2


        }       


        private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void {
            for (var i:uint=0; i<goldContainer.numChildren; i++) {
                var fallingGold:Gold=goldContainer.getChildAt(i) as Gold;
                if (fallingGold.y<fallingGold.destinationY) {
                    fallingGold.y++;
                } else {
                    fallingGold.alpha-=0.01;
                    if (fallingGold.alpha<0) {

                        goldContainer.removeChild(fallingGold);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Gold class :

```
package
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite
    import flash.events.MouseEvent

    public class Gold extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _main:Main
        private var gold:Gold;


        public function Gold(main:Main):void 
        {

            _main=main;
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goldClicked);

        }

        private function goldClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goldClicked);
            _main.goldContainer.removeChild(e.currentTarget as Gold);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: could you tell us at what line the error gets thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From first glance, you don't have a `destinationY` property in your `Gold` Class. `MovieClip` does not have this property either, so you're trying to manipulate a variable that doesn't exist.

Unless this isn't the whole Class you're showing us, of course.

To elaborate a bit

> I don't use the destinationY property in Gold class. Only in main
>   class.

Yes, but the you're trying to manipulate a property called destinationY in your Gold Class **from** the main class.

If you do this:

```
public class Gold extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _main:Main
        private var gold:Gold;
        public var destinationY:int = 0;
        ...
    }
```

you shouldn't get this error anymore, but i doubt this will solve all your problems.

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining it! At first, I tried combining all the codes in 1 main class and gold.destinationY works perfectly without being defined in public var, then I tried to seperate it into gold class and main class. I never knew if it needs to be defined in the other class first. Anyway, can you please explain too why gold.destinationY works if it's only in main class without being defined in public var? I haven't really understood about these things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On line xx of the Main class, you have the code:

```
gold.destinationY = 35+goldRow*75;
```

You're trying to access the "destinationY" property of the Gold class, but the Gold class doesn't have a public property named destinationY. To add it, just add this line to the Gold class:

```
public var destinationY;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know before that it needs to be defined in the other class too. Because when I tried putting all in 1 class. destinationY doesn't need to be defined in public var and it still works. any idea why did that happen?